# Lost my Gimp menu

Tags: ubuntu-mate, gimp

I do not know what the exact name it should be called, but I lost my Gimp menu.

[image]

This is what I lost.

[image]

Comment: Which version and flavour of Ubuntu is it? Which version of `gimp`? Have you tried to purge and after that re-install `gimp`?

Comment: @sudodus Ubuntu Mate 18.04 Purge and reinstall did not help.

Comment: Can you remember some modification that you did recently (modification of the MATE desktop system)?

Comment: Not that I recall.

Comment: Is it the version that is installed via `apt`, or is it installed some other way, for example snap or ppa or flatpak?

Comment: Previously I used synaptic. But recently I did it using apt.

Comment: are we sure we're looking for something in the Mate user bar? @fixit7 are you looking for sothing that's a OS-side indicator or are you trying to get back a part of the gimp interface?

Comment: I am also using `apt` to install `gimp`. I use it in Ubuntu and Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (with the Bionic kernel series) and up to date. I have not had your problem. Maybe the problem is specific to MATE and because some program package was upgraded. Let us hope someone who had and solved the problem will see this and help you. Otherwise I suggest that you create a bug report at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net)

Comment: I am trying to get back my menu bar in Gimp. I believe it used to be right on top of the opened picture. If you want to upload of pic of what your Gimp looks like when opened, it would help.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to restore the default toolbox windows in GIMP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461152/how-to-restore-the-default-toolbox-windows-in-gimp/461178#461178)

Comment: @steeldriver I tried it. No luck. I have a clonezilla image from 3/15/19. If I can not get it resolved within a few days, I will restore it.

Comment: Ubuntu Mate 18.04 i386 (32-bit) or amd64 (64-bit)?

Comment: I installed it using the Gimp flatpak. Everything is good now. :-)

Comment: Congratulations, you solved it yourself :-)

Comment: Now to find where the flatpak is.

Comment: I think the flatpak is where you put it, maybe in your `Downloads` directory. If you want to check where it installed `gimp`, you can use the command `which gimp` and `find /usr -iname "*gimp*"` and check for configuration files in your home directory, for example with `find ~ -iname "*gimp*"`

Comment: I installed the gimp flatpak using software.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91376/discussion-between-sudodus-and-fixit7).

Answer (score 3):

In Gimp 2.8 & 2.10:

[image]

Click the `Reset` button at the bottom to go back to factory settings.

In practice this kind of setting is in your [Gimp profile](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/).

Reinstalling Gimp doesn't fix anything since the Profile is not rewritten (it is more efficient to erase/rename the profile (without reinstalling) to have Gimp recreate a new one).

Installing the next version doesn't fix it either since Gimp migrates your profile to the new version. In your case it worked because your previous version was too old to be considered for migration and Gimp created a new profile with the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to purge gimp and reinstalling, I had no luck.

I decided to try installing Gimp using software.

It used a flatpak and now my menu is present.